# How to run latest SVN revision script via Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I've installed svn server on my Centos 6.4 machine. I have currenty one repo and one subdomain. I want to link this subdomain to run latest repo revision. I don't know how to do that, because there is no project structure in svn server side directory (project files are compiled into one or something like that).

My subversion.conf is like:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
<Location /r>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn    
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "My Subversion"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
      Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And here is my apache domain's virtual host:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/public"
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/subdomain.domain.com:/var/zpanel/temp/"
    php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "passthru, show_source, shell_exec, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_terminate, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, escapeshellcmd, escapeshellarg, exec"
    ErrorLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/subdomain.domain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/subdomain.domain.com-access.log" combined
    CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/subdomain.domain.com-bandwidth.log" common
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 .php
    ErrorDocument 510 /_errorpages/510.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /_errorpages/404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /_errorpages/500.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /_errorpages/403.html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</virtualhost>
```

Is there any posibility to do that?

Comment: Setup a hook script, so that when an update is pushed to the server it triggers a update in the working copy served served out by Apache.

Comment: export the project from svn server to your subdomain folder

Comment: Look into FSVS (fsvs.tigris.org) as an alternative to using "svn export" commands.  With FSVS, only the files that have changed will be pushed over the wire instead of every file.  And you don't need a ".svn" folder (if you go the "svn update" route).

Answer (score 0):

Set up a post-commit hook that runs:

```
svn export file:///var/www/svn/your-repo  /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/public
```

A sample hook should be available in your hooks directory at /var/www/svn/your-repo/hooks .  You can customize it to meet your needs.